# Can I stop the pop every time I scroll over a video?

Tags: audio, windows-11

Scrolling on twitter or facebook, my speakers make a loud pop when a video scrolls into view. My machine must be opening a connection to the speakers. I've read that pops have something to do with the lack of smooth caching, but I can find no settings. I'm on Windows 11, with an acer swift 5 laptop, and external speakers connected via the 3.5mm audio jack. I there anything I can do?

Comment: Does using a different browser, or different audio output (different speakers, the laptop's speakers, headphones, etc), have a different result?